# Notation in different articles about HMM

Tags: terminology, hidden-markov-model, notation

I'm studying hidden Markov models, especially the articles by [Stamp (2018)](http://www.cs.sjsu.edu/~stamp/RUA/HMM.pdf) and [Rabiner (1989)](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/rabiner.pdf). Please let me check with you that I got this right:

[image]

Especially the last observation is my own, about the difference in notation between the two authors.